# Django - NameError when trying to call model method in views

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I have a method in my model that I would like to call in my views. However, I get a `NameError` that this function is not defined (I have imported all models in my views and all migrations are up to date). It has worked for other functions in the past.

Here is my model:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    """
    fields
    """

    def lyrics_as_list(self):
       return self.lyrics_ru.split()

    def sorted_strings(self, strings, locale=None):
       if locale is None:
           return sorted(strings)
       collator = icu.Collator.createInstance(icu.Locale(locale))
       return sorted(strings, key=collator.getSortKey)
```

And in my views the relevant part where I want to use it:

```
lyrics_list = models.Song.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk']).lyrics_as_list() #this is also a method on my model, and it does work
lyrics_sorted = sorted_strings(set(lyrics_list, "ru_RU.UTF8")) #but this one gives me an error
```

The error: `name 'sorted_strings' is not defined`

When I move the method to my views, it works. But I have to use this in several views, so I am trying to follow the DRY principle, and so it would be great to get it to work.

**Edit** - What the `sorted_strings` function is for:
My `Song` model contains lyrics. I am displaying all words in the lyrics in a table, but I want to show it alphabetically. In order to be able to sort Russian words, I needed to add this function.

Comment: I fail to see a good reason to include the method `sorted_strings` in the class `Song`. Not only the naming is bad - methods should rather define action, have a verb in the name, a better name would be `sort_strings` - but it doesn't describe any behaviour of an object `Song`. If there's an argument to keep it inside `Song`, better make it a static method with the decorator `@staticmethod`.

Comment: @cezar Thanks, points taken. If not in my `Song` model, then where should I put it?

Comment: In order to give you an appropriate answer I'd need to know much more about your project. Please try to reflect how to better describe the functionality you try to implement. The name `sorted_strings` is very vague. What kind of strings?

Comment: I've edited my question to explain what the function is for @cezar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `sorted strings` as defined in the class `Song`:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    """
    fields
    """

    def sorted_strings(self, strings, locale=None):
        if locale is None:
            return sorted(strings)
        collator = icu.Collator.createInstance(icu.Locale(locale))
        return sorted(strings, key=collator.getSortKey)
```

cannot be called like this:

```
sorted_strings(strings, locale)
```

This obviously leads to a `NameError`. It is a method, so you need to call it on an object as instance of that class.

You might get tempted to try this:

```
Song.sorted_strigns(strings, locale)
```

but it won't work. It will result in missing 1 required positional argument. That is you have to provide `self`. You can't call it directly on the class.

If you introspect this method well, it doesn't perform any action on an object. The argument `self` is not used. You'd like to call it without instantiating an object, but directly on the class. Therefore you can use the decorator `@staticmethod`:

```
@staticmethod
def sorted_strings(strings, locale=None):
    if locale is None:
        return sorted(strings)
    collator = icu.Collator.createInstance(icu.Locale(locale))
    return sorted(strings, key=collator.getSortKey)
```

Please notice how the static method doesn't need to be passed the argument `self`.

Now your code should work like this:

```
lyrics_list = Song.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk']).lyrics_as_list()
lyrics_sorted = Song.sorted_strings(set(lyrics_list), "ru_RU.UTF8")
```

Also in your code example you have an error with the parentheses in the second line.

Besides static methods, there are also class methods, defined using the decorator `@classmethod`. For this purpose here I'd go with the static method, but if someone has an objection, I'm ready to learn.

Static methods are not very common in Python and frowned upon by many.
Nevertheless it's good to know they exist and how they work.

Comment: I moved the method to a different file called `methods.py` and then imported it and it's working. So now I can put all methods that I want to reuse and are not specific to `Song` in this file. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MeL That's sensible to create a separate file for this purpose. However I'd suggest to rename the file from `methods.py` to `utils.py`. Django uses the name `utils` too and actually you don't have methods in that file but functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
lyrics_list = models.Song.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk']).lyrics_as_list()
lyrics_sorted = models.Song.objects.sorted_strings(set(lyrics_list), "ru_RU.UTF8")
```

Manager's method can only be called with `Model.objects`

Comment: Add some explanation as to how this solves the question